# Emptying a directory owned by another user weekly

Tags: permissions, sudo, cron

I have a temp directory set up where users can place whatever files they need to send to other users via HTTP.  The owner of this directory is an SFTP user, and cannot run cron jobs.

I have one shell user that can run cron jobs, but does not have permission to edit files in the SFTP user's directory.

I have an admin user that can access the SFTP user's directory when using sudo, but can't (read: I'd really rather not) run cron jobs.

So, here's the conundrum. How do I get a nightly cron job to run as a shell user to delete files older than 1 week within the SFTP user's directory, with the admin user's privileges?

Comment: And the reason why can't you run a system cron job as the SFTP user is ...?

Comment: No shell access

Comment: What is your preferred approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/sudoers` file (use `visudo`!) and add an entry that allows the shell user to have sufficient privileges to run a specific command, without having to enter a password. If you use a script, make sure the script cannot by edited by anyone but root.

In `/etc/sudoers`, where `shelluser` is the shell user name:

`shelluser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/clean-up-sftp-temp-directory`

In a `/usr/bin/clean-up-sftp-temp-directory` script, you can put something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -f /home/sftpuser/will-be-deleted/*
```

After making the script executable, you should be able to call `sudo clean-up-sftp-temp-directory` and add it to the shell user's crontab.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  For some reason I was having lots of trouble with the sudoers file before I posted the question (kept complaining about a syntax error). Copying your line almost verbatim fixed the problem nice and quick.

Comment: Make sure, nobody can replace "will-be-deleted" with a symlink to /etc/ for instance. Also, if it doesn't need root priviledge, don't give it root privilege (use `sudo -u the-user-who-as-the-right` and replace the ALL with that user in `sudoers`)